# How to search for few files out of hundred files in UNIX and if not find replace with 0 byte file

Tags: unix

I need a shell script to search and replace a file. Details are below. Pl help

1. Basically everyday i get some files into my directory.Like below i get 100 files

AllResponses_11003_6_20_2013.txt

AllResponses_11004_6_20_2013.txt

AllResponses_11005_6_20_2013.txt

AllResponses_11006_6_20_2013.txt

AllResponses_11007_6_20_2013.txt

AllResponses_11008_6_20_2013.txt

AllResponses_11009_6_20_2013.txt

AllResponses_11010_6_20_2013.txt

AllResponses_11011_6_20_2013.txt

AllResponses_11012_6_20_2013.txt

1. Among those i need to copy 5 files to another directory based on file number(11003,11004,11005,11006,11007)

AllResponses_11003_6_20_2013.txt

AllResponses_11004_6_20_2013.txt

AllResponses_11005_6_20_2013.txt

AllResponses_11006_6_20_2013.txt

AllResponses_11007_6_20_2013.txt

1. If not find , then need to replace with 0 byte files for those 5 files into another directory.

Pl help

But how to pass num as 11003,11004,11005,11006,11007 among hundreds of numbers like 11003 to 11100

Pl help...

export SRCDIR=/informat/PowerCenter/9.1.0/server/infa_shared/SrcFiles/CSI/historical

export TGTDIR=/informat/PowerCenter/9.1.0/server/infa_shared/SrcFiles/CSI/incoming

export FILEDT=6_15_2013

## export FILEDT=$(date +"%-m_%-d_%Y")

## looping for to search and copy files

for FILE_NUM in "$@";

do

GET_FNAME="AllResponses_"${FILE_NUM}"_"${FILEDT}"*.txt"

if [ -f ${GET_FNAME} ]; then

cp ${SRCDIR}/${GET_FNAME} ${TGTDIR}

else

echo "File ${GET_FNAME} is missing in ${SRCDIR}"

touch ${TGTDIR}/AllResponses_${FILE_NUM}_${FILEDT}.txt

echo "Created ${GET_FNAME} touch file in ${TGTDIR}"

fi done

iam done like above and executing as ksh -x csi_file_copy_bala.ksh 11003 11004 99999

but its always going to else clause..please help me...

my files nales looks like...AllResponses_11004_6_11_20132_18_00AM1.txt

Pl help me...as iam running out of time

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Assuming by shell u mean bash:

Skeleton to start with:

```
luk32:~/projects/tests$ cat ./process_files.sh
#!/bin/bash
DEST=./copies
for num in "$@"; do
 file="AllResponses_"$num"_6_20_2013.txt"
 if [ -f $file ]; then
  cp $file $DEST
 else
  touch $DEST/$file
 fi
done;
```

It takes numbers as arguments, then tries to find a file with given pattern in current working directory. If found copy to destination folder, else `touch` the file.
You will probably have to tinker a little bit to get friendlier than hard-coded date handling.

Example:

```
luk32:~/projects/tests$ ls -l
total 40116
-rw-r--r-- 1 luk32 luk32        4 cze 21 11:33 AllResponses_1_6_20_2013.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 luk32 luk32        5 cze 21 11:33 AllResponses_3_6_20_2013.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 luk32 luk32        0 cze 21 11:32 AllResponses_4_6_20_2013.txt
luk32:~/projects/tests$ ls -l ./copies/
total 0
luk32:~/projects/tests$ ./process_files.sh 1 2 3 4
luk32:~/projects/tests$ ls -l ./copies/
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 luk32 luk32 4 cze 21 11:35 AllResponses_1_6_20_2013.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 luk32 luk32 0 cze 21 11:35 AllResponses_2_6_20_2013.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 luk32 luk32 5 cze 21 11:35 AllResponses_3_6_20_2013.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 luk32 luk32 0 cze 21 11:35 AllResponses_4_6_20_2013.txt
```

Comment: Thanks...but one more help.....But how to pass num as 11003,11004,11005,11006,11007 among hundreds of numbers like 11003 to 11100 in the for loop

Comment: You need to be more specific, do you always need a range? `seq 11003 11050` will generate range. Look `man seq`. You need to figure out how get the numbers it its more complicated. Then you can pass them by hand or embed it within the script.

Comment: You can do it like this, `./process_files.sh {11003..11100}`

Comment: I do usually `./process_files.sh \`seq 1 100`\` but its just a different syntax I guess. If you embed a command within `\`cmd\`` it will get expanded into a string it this place. So, normally `seq` produces numbers, but in this context its output will be placed as the command line arguments.

Comment: Er.. I meant its output will get placed in its place. I often use it with `ls` and `seq`. Like `./do_magic_to.sh \`ls AllResponses*\``.

Comment: export SRCDIR=/informat/PowerCenter/9.1.0/server/infa_shared/SrcFiles/CSI/historical
export TGTDIR=/informat/PowerCenter/9.1.0/server/infa_shared/SrcFiles/CSI/incoming
export FILEDT=6_15_2013
#export FILEDT=$(date +"%-m_%-d_%Y")

# looping for to search and copy files
for FILE_NUM in "$@"; do
 GET_FNAME="AllResponses_"${FILE_NUM}"_"${FILEDT}"*.txt"
 if [ -f ${GET_FNAME} ]; then
cp ${SRCDIR}/${GET_FNAME} ${TGTDIR}
 else
 echo "File ${GET_FNAME} is missing in ${SRCDIR}"
  touch ${TGTDIR}/AllResponses_${FILE_NUM}_${FILEDT}.txt
  echo "Created ${GET_FNAME} touch file in ${TGTDIR}"
 fi
done

Comment: hi iam done like that and executing ksh -x csi_file_copy_bala.ksh 11003 11004 99999 ...like this but always going to else clause..please help me...

Comment: my files nales looks like...AllResponses_11004_6_11_20132_18_00AM1.txt